# trying to display a Sum on template of each instance of a class field filtered by another field on that same class. python django fantasy sports

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

[screen shot of the fantasy team roster page]

I am trying to build a fantasy sports website. I have NBA players (as a class) assigned to (django's built-in) Users (the fantasy team) via a field on the Player Class. I want to sum all of a User's players' salaries for a given year and list that on that User's (aka team's) Player roster page (regardless of who is signed in.) I was able to get this Sum on the django shell for a specific user_id:

imported Player class to shell & django.db.models import Sum
Player.objects.filter(player_owner__exact='1').aggregate(Sum('player_sal_19_20'))

result: {'player_sal_19_20__sum': Decimal('89654339')}

**But how can I get this sum on the template for the fantasy team's public roster page?**

I have spent days trying the aggregate function, trying to incorporate it with my get_queryset (see views snippet) function, template tags, and some other methods that went way over my head.

I am using django's built-in Users as my teams and have created a player class on models.py:

```
class Player(models.Model):
  player_full = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  player_sal_19_20 = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  player_sal_20_21 = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  player_sal_21_22 = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  player_sal_22_23 = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
  player_owner = models.ForeignKey(User, default='26', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then I created a view for a User's players page on views.py:

```
class UserPlayerListView(ListView):
  model = Player
  template_name = 'blog/user_players.html'
  context_object_name = 'players'
  paginate_by = 20

  def get_queryset(self):
      user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
      return Player.objects.filter(player_owner=user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Finally I was able to map out the easy stuff on the html template with loops. But alas, I am at a road block when it comes to querying a a group of players' annual salary filtered by their assigned fantasy User.

just to be clear, this is what i need:
Sum the 'player_sal_19_20' field for each player that appears on a team's roster which is determined by the player's 'fantasy_owner' field.

I am pretty new to django and python. I assume this is actually easy to do, so i apologize in advance if this is the case. Also, if anyone knows of examples of people using python/django for a fantasy sports site, that'd be helpful too!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you trying to sum all fields in the `Player` model?

Comment: Thank's for the response! I am trying to sum the 'player_sal_19_20' field from Player A and Player B ...etc as long as those players have the 'player_owner' value of "User 1". if a player has a different 'player_owner' value like "User 2" they should be excluded from the sum. Ideally, that 'player_owner' value that's used to filter the included/excluded should be the owner (aka User) who's page we are viewing. I was able to do this with the pagination on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this by overriding `get_context_data(...)` method:

```
class UserPlayerListView(ListView):
  # rest of the code
  def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context(**kwargs)
      context['sum_of_salary'] = context['players'].aggregate(players_sum=Sum('player_sal_19_20'))['players_sum']
      return context
```

Then use it in template:

```
{{ sum_of_salary }}
```

### update

(*From comments*) as you have multiple attributes you would like to aggregate, then try like this:

```
class UserPlayerListView(ListView):
      # rest of the code
      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
          context = super().get_context(**kwargs)
          context['sum_sal_19_20'] = context['players'].aggregate(players_sum=Sum('player_sal_19_20'))['players_sum']
          context['sum_sal_20_21'] = context['players'].aggregate(players_sum=Sum('player_sal_20_21'))['players_sum']
          # and so on
          return context
```

Then use it in template:

```
{{ sum_sal_19_20 }}
{{ sum_sal_20_21 }}
// and so on
```

But in this solution, it will hitting database multiple times when you call `aggregate()`. So I would recommend you should [evaluate the queryset to list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) and calculate `sum` in pythonic way. For example:

```
class UserPlayerListView(ListView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context(**kwargs)
        player_list = list(context['players'])  # evaluates the query
        context['sum_sal_19_20'] = sum([x.player_sal_19_20 for x in player_list])  # pythonic sum calculation
        context['sum_sal_20_21'] = sum([x.player_sal_20_21 for x in player_list])
        # and so on
        context['players'] = player_list          
        return context
```

### More elegant solution

You can simply use group by get value:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context(**kwargs)
    players_salary_values = list(
        context['players'].values('player_owner').annotate(
            salary_19_20=Sum('player_sal_19_20'),
            salary_20_21=Sum('player_sal_20_21')
        ).values(
            'salary_19_20', 
            'salary_20_21'
        )
    )[0]
    # as there is only one player owner here, you can use 1st index of the list
    context.update(players_salary_values)
    return context
```

Comment: I had to add _data in there:
`super().get_context**_data**(**kwargs).`

So now my final code for the view def is:

`def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['sum_of_sal_19_20'] = context['players'].aggregate(players_sum=Sum('player_sal_19_20'))['players_sum']
        return context`


But Wow that worked! thanks!


Now, obvious followup:

I was able to get this to work on the players' 2019/20 salary, but how can I get it to work on the other salary years as well? I tried a few adjustments but they all failed.

Comment: oh I see, ok, i'll try this method out to see if that works. Can you explain why this method is better? Am I painting myself into a corner when I hit the database multiple times?

Comment: Multiple DB hits is not good in any way. Like lets say 5000 people are at your website and hitting database 5 times for a page in a simple GET request, it is hitting 25000 times. Please see the updated answer again, I have added a more sophisticated solution with even less code.

Comment: if you are able, could you try and help me with this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62945436/class-based-view-sum-used-for-class-based-form-validation-without-forms-py

Answer (score 0):

@ruddra total nailed it, thanks!

I messed around with it a little more and was able to simply add more context dicts(?) under the def to get each year's salary total:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
      context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
      context['sum_of_sal_19_20'] = context['players'].aggregate(players_sum=Sum('player_sal_19_20'))['players_sum']
      context['sum_of_sal_20_21'] = context['players'].aggregate(players_sum=Sum('player_sal_20_21'))['players_sum']
      context['sum_of_sal_21_22'] = context['players'].aggregate(players_sum=Sum('player_sal_21_22'))['players_sum']
      context['sum_of_sal_22_23'] = context['players'].aggregate(players_sum=Sum('player_sal_22_23'))['players_sum']
      return context
```

then I was able to simply use the 'sum_of_sal_19_20' in the template as {{ sum_of_sal_19_20 }}

Next i'll try figuring out how to use these numbers towards salary caps, calculating cap penalties and all that fun stuff. Also going to try and tackle player trading between users. Thanks again!